# The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I know this issue was discussed before several times, but I cant get the solution to my problem from any of the answers,

My contract got deployed fine before adding the following function,

```
function setApproval(address addr, bool approved)payable returns(string, uint, uint) {

       //some logical operations and assignments

    }
```

as soon as I add the function and try to deploy the contract, 
I got this error

> Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transactions manually. Error: The contract code couldn't be stored,
>   please check your gas amount.

test rpc server shows following logs

> Transaction:
>   0xd5791ac0c6059cbd43e00a7fabe566ada3f0572966f12ff25da6e04215840f39
>   Contract created: 0x9062592c5dd06340401c1e750ddb025defabf5be Gas
>   usage: 4712388 Block Number: 16 Block Time: Sat Jul 22 2017 03:30:30
>   GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Runtime Error: out of gas

again after removing this function contract deployed without errors

what is wrong with this function?

My contract code is around 250 lines, is there any limit on contract code size??

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you deploying the contract? Try to increase the `gasLimit` setting, if any.

Comment: How are you deploying your contract? If you put your code we can help you with a modified version. To modify the gas amount for a single transaction you do something like this `eth.sendTransaction(params...., { gas: 10000000 })`.

Comment: @jeff I am deploying the code using truffle console, Is it possible to increase the gas limit in Azure Ethereum Consortium Blockchain

Comment: @Ismael I am getting the error while deploying contract, Its not about single transaction, the contract without  `setApproval()` funnction is getting deployed without any error and I can call the functions with the method you have suggested, but as soon as I add this particular function and try to redeploy the contract I get the error message which I have specified in the question

Comment: @ jeff The command I am using for deployment `truffle migrate --reset`

Comment: @SwapnilKumbhar I don't know about Truffle. Maybe you can try another deployment method ([MEW](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) provides one) to better identify the problem. Also a payable constant method seems strange to me, since constant functions should be "free". Not sure if it's legal though.

Comment: Its not a constant function, may be you are confused by `retrurns`

Comment: @SwapnilKumbhar If the error only appear after adding a new function the cause is very likely you run out of gas when deploying. So you should increase the amount of gas. I think in truffle you have to modify your deploying function to something like `deployer.deploy(MyContract, params.., {gas: 5000000});` increasing the amount of gas if necessary.

Comment: What's the code inside setApproval? If without that function it is working, then the problem must have to do with the code you omitted in the question.

Comment: @pabloruiz55 code inside the setApproval () doesn't  affect the result I have tried commenting the code, finally after reading some articles I came to assumption that the size of code  is limited in Azure ethereum consortium blockchain, as the max. gas limit for a block is 4712388.

Answer (score 2):

In your `2_deploy_contracts.js` file, change the gas <del>price</del> defaults to a higher number, i.e.:

```
// 2_deploy_contracts.js

const MyContract = artifacts.require('./MyContract.sol')

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MyContract, { gas: 5000000 })
}
```

I had the same issue and this worked for me.

Comment: this works with testrpc, I have tried using this with Azure etherum consortium blockchain network, its doesn't work, finally after reading some articles I came to the assumption that the size of code is limited in Azure ethereum consortium blockchain, as the max. gas limit for a block is 4712388. I believe this is the limitation of Azure ethereum consortium blockchain.

Comment: @SwapnilKumbhar, I'm using also Azure Ethereum Consortium Blockchain network and encounter this error when I try to deploy a contract throw my dApp. But it works well for the same contract if I deploy it throw Remix.
I don't know what's my problem, but it seems something with the process of deploy and not the contract size or gas required

Comment: @dchang Can you share your  contract code here? that will be helpful to debug your issue, For Now I will suggest try to reduce Lines Of Code and try to deploy. Better try removing some heavy function, If it works then logically divide your contract in to multiple contracts and deploy them individually, I have applied this solution when I faced the issue with some large contracts.

Comment: @SwapnilKumbhar As already stated, the problem it's not the contract it self, as I can deploy with remix. And to discard it I'm trying with a very simple contract: "pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

contract TestContrato{
  
}". You can't have simpler than that. Additional note: I'm not using truffle, instead I'm trying to user only web3 (version 1.0.0-beta.36), using deploy() method or sending a raw transfer with data: bytecode

Answer (score 2):

When a contract inherits from interface and doesn't implement a function this error will be issued.

Truffle 4.0.4
solc 0.4.18

```
interface IF { 
    function doSomething() external view returns(uint); 
}

contract Inherit is IF {
    Inherit() public; 
}
```

when deployed. will issue error:

> The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

solution is to implement the function.

```
contract Inherit is IF {
    doSomething() external view returns(uint) {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem which happens rarely but causes exactly the same error message is the following:

**Currently, contract code size is limited to 24KB, and sometimes, your bytecode can be greater than it, which will cause the exact same issue.**

> Go to your contract build json file, and check if the deployed
>   bytecode size is greater than 24Kb.

Solution:
This can be solved by various contract optimizations such as removing sufficient getters, public declarations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have used @rhlsthrm solution with extra modification because his solution gave me

> Error: exceeds block gas limit

My solution is for Geth.

First, get gas limit from latest block

using

```
eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit
```

copy the gas limit and then paste it like this

```
var Identity = artifacts.require("./Identity.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Identity, { gas: 794722 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

increase gas value in you deploy file.

if you log the deploy error, you can see gas detail, like this :

```
cumulativeGasUsed: 1217170,
effectiveGasPrice: 2500000011,
gasUsed: 1000000,
```

please check if the 'gasUsed' is smaller than 'cumulativeGasUsed' so you shall increase gas value in you deploy code setting, like this :

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({
      data: evm.bytecode.object,
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000 });
```

change gas value (1000000) to (2000000) like this :

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({
      data: evm.bytecode.object,
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 2000000 });
```